# Batch If statement gives " was unexpected at this time" and crashes

Tags: batch-file

This program (and programs I've worked on in the past) would always crash the program and stop it from working properly. Meanwhile, if I removed them, the code within worked fine. I've included pause commands to see the source of the problem and the problem starts within the first line of the if statement.

```
echo (: Gold Fish Game :)
echo ####################
echo 1 - Begin Journey
echo 2 - Tragic Backstory
echo 3 - Exit This 
set /p choice = "Choose one dude "

if %choice% == 1 (
    goto S1L1
)
if %choice% == 2 (
    goto MenuBackstory
)
if %choice% == 3 (
    exit
)
```

Comment: `%choice%` is empty. You defined `%choice %` instead. But anyway - I recommend using the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command instead.

Comment: Huh...what do ya know? Thx!

Comment: @FrederickMatson, the HELP syntax for using the `SET` command is clearly defined as not showing a space between the variable and the assignment operator. `SET [variable=[string]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong command, the `Set /P` command accepts nothing at all, or absolutely anything as input, and requires a very robust validation procedure before using that input elsewhere.

You should therefore use the `choice` command utility. Open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, and read the usage information.

Example:

```py
Echo (: Gold Fish Game :)
Echo ####################
Echo 1 - Begin Journey
Echo 2 - Tragic Backstory
Echo 3 - Exit This 
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 123 /M "What is your chosen item number"
If ErrorLevel 3 Exit /B
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo MenuBackstory

:S1L1
```